# Why is padding not appearing for this css class?

Tags: css, netbeans, wordpress-theming

I am learning to use Netbeans and gulp to develop in Wordpress, following a great tutorial at lynda.com. I have sass set up to compile the partial .scss files into the style.css file for the project, which compiles fine.

However, when I attempt to add padding around a specific class, the CSS does not take effect. I can see that the code was added in the style.css file here:

```
site-content {
    padding: 2em;
}
```

and that it was included in the style sheet for the page; but when the webpage is rendered, no padding appears (as it does in the tutorial).

I thought maybe some other CSS could be overriding the padding, and found this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='casse_dev-style-css'  href='//192.168.0.26:8080/wp-content/themes/casse_dev/style.css?ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='//192.168.0.26:8080/wp-json/' />
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="//192.168.0.26:8080/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="//192.168.0.26:8080/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.8" />
        <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>

</head>
```

The css code is in the included style sheet, style.css, in the first line.

I don't see how the !important;padding:0 could be interfering, since that should only be affecting the .recentcomments id selector, but that's the only other clue I have at the moment.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: The selector is `.recentcomments a`, so all links inside .recentcomments will not have Padding. And your selector is wrong. You need to do `.site-content` (class selector) or `#site-content` (id selector), not `site-content`

Answer (score 1):

The selector is `.recentcomments a`, so all links inside `.recentcomments` will not have Padding.

And your selector is wrong. You need to do `.site-content{}` (class selector) or `#site-content{}` (id selector), not `site-content{}`

Comment: Thanks much...it was indeed the lack of using correct class selector syntax.